# What is the experience on Norwegian Cruises with a rollator/walker?

Tags: health, cruising, accessibility

Has anybody here taken a Norwegian Cruise Line trip while temporarily disabled and using a rollator/walker? If so, could you kindly give your thoughts on accessibility, accommodations, and general satisfaction with the cruise line's services for those with mobility issues?

Comment: What is the problem you actually face?

Comment: Cruise travel is populair by older people and many of those do keep going on cruises when walking gets more difficult. I bet you will not be the only one with a walking aid on board. Likely not by a long way.

Comment: If you perform a search (i.e. Google, Bing, etc) for "Royal Norwegian Cruise accessibility)  you'll get plenty of hits and contact information.

Answer (score 11):

I have not cruised with a rollator, however I have cruised with NCL many times and will share my observations.  On my last cruise (a couple months ago) I had injured my foot not long before and had to use a cane, so while not the same I still would have struggled with steps and ramps but had no problems at all.

There is nowhere on the ship that *requires* a guest to use stairs.  Everywhere - staterooms, restaurants, decks, theatres - are all accessible.  There are stairs for guests that can use them, but there are also elevators/lifts, ramps, easy entry.

Restaurants are easy access, and they will seat you where it is easy for you to access.  The buffet has designated accessible seating (with extra space around them) if you want to use them, but you're not required to if you want to sit elsewhere (I recommend you skip the buffet anyway - the restaurants are far better!)

If you book and say you need an accessible stateroom they'll give you one.  Some of these have wider doors (for large wheelchairs), and others are just laid out slightly differently to make it more accessible.

There are some ramps or sloping decks.  To me these have always appeared gradual and are well marked.  I've seen people with rollators and in wheelchairs navigate these easily.  In fact I've seen them navigate most parts of the ship without problem.  If there is any difficulty there are always staff/crew nearby who are happy to help if you need it.

The only part I'm unsure about is the bathrooms - in a standard stateroom there is a small step into the bathroom.  I would assume the accessible ones are set up differently to this, however I've never had an accessible room, and on my quick glance into one on my last cruise I didn't pay particular attention to that. Edit - @[Sneftel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67695/sneftel) has commented to say:

> *I've had an accessible NCL stateroom. Main differences: wider doors
> and corridors; the balcony door was electric and had a ramp for the
> threshold; the bathroom door had no threshold; the bathroom itself had
> a roll-in shower with a seat, and more grab bars than you could shake
> a Zimmer frame at.*

TL;DR - I think you'll be fine, you will be well looked after.  Just let the cruise line know that you'll have a rollator and may need help, and request an accessible room if you need it.

Comment: I've had an accessible NCL stateroom. Main differences: wider doors and corridors; the balcony door was electric and had a ramp for the threshold; the bathroom door had no threshold; the bathroom itself had a roll-in shower with a seat, and more grab bars than you could shake a Zimmer frame at.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's great to hear that NCL is accommodating to those with mobility issues. I'll request an accessible stateroom and let them know about my rollator. Thanks again for the peace of mind!

Answer (score 3):

I never sailed with such devices (nor in Norwegian), but I saw several people with it, and few also with carts, in many cruises.

First: check if you can enjoy such cruise (else, if you have insurance, or talking with cruise line, you may be able to postpone it). Some cruises are better then others.

What to check: in general: larger cruise ships must uses larger ports, so with more infrastructure. On the other hand on a large cruise you may have much more too walk.  Try to avoid cruises with tenders at some port of calls (so ships which will not dock, but you need to take a boat for a ride of few minutes). Also try to avoid ports where you cruise line already tell that there is few infrastructure (it may happens on some places where there are not many ships docking (yearly, not on a specific day)). So avoid most "exploration" and "adventure" style cruises. Also check if you can enjoy the itinerary: visiting cities may be easier then exploring nature.

In any case, I saw people using such devices also on short nature trails, or city walks. It is much up to you (and your strength: such devices are additional weight you must move).

Seconds: speak with your cruise line. Most cruise lines are based in US, and so they must take disabilities very seriously: they will move in a more suitable cabin (if it is available): usually with larger doors, and near elevators). They eventually tell you about the maximum dimension or other rules about security (every country may have different rules). It should not be a problem, but better to know in advance.

For the cruise: you will not find much problems. Most cruise lines have many activities also for non sporty people. You can reach nearly all ship without stairs (but few sport places, or view on top decks).

You may get on the forum of CruiseCritics: it has huge community, and in every cruise there are members, so you can ask people which were on a similar cruise as you plan to sail (in this site we are much more generalist, and we are not a forum by design).